# Why is my program not connecting to the database?

Tags: c#, database, sqlcommand

I'm creating a database so I can store usernames and passwords. I have successfully created a DB on Microsft Visual Express C# 2010.

My program seems to be working fine, and produces no error message, except that I'm not getting any feedback: it looks like my program is not actually making the request to the database, or not returning the results. What's going on?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Did not connect");
        }
        string username = textBox1.Text;
        string password = maskedTextBox1.Text;
        string sqlquery = ("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username = '" + textBox1.Text + "'");
        sqlquery = "INSERT INFO [User] (Username, Password) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "')";
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cn);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", username);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", password);
    }
    private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Did not connect");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Chances are you're using the wrong connection string.  "Microsft visual Express C# 2010" is not a product, I assume you mean through Visual Studio Express.  How did you create the database?

Comment: You say that you get no feedback, so your program just runs or...?

Comment: remove the try/catch blocks as these are swallowing the actual error. you can review the error type, message and stack trace to determine what the exact problem is. also the try catches will create more problem when the user clicks "ok" on the msg box.

Comment: i think its visual studio express but i am using the C# Version of it. i created the DB on the program itself it has options to create a database just as you would on SQL server management express. or MYSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually executing the `SqlCommand`, so it seems logical that you would not "see" anything happen. Try adding the following line to the end of `button1_Click`:

```
Command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // actually execute the INSERT INFO... query
```

You have some issues with your SQL code, but you'll receive exceptions for them once you execute the command.

Comment: good catch. also, you'll want to properly dispose of the ado.net objects to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: There are quite a number of improvements which could be made, however, this being homework for the OP I've left out more than the problem at hand.

Comment: now i am getting feedback. i got an error but now i have something to work off thanks Six.